# Android Navigation Component : Pass value (arguments) in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

### What I have done:

I have created **Navigation Drawer Activity**, As updated new format of **Navigation Drawer Activity**, As per new Android architecture, I got it with **[Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)** structure.

The `NavigationView` code with `NavController` and `NavigationUI` is below which is **opening fragment when I click on any navigation item.**

```java
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
// Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
// menu should be considered as top level destinations.
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
        R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_profile, R.id.nav_privacy_policy,
        R.id.nav_terms, R.id.nav_contact_us, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
        .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
        .build();
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

This is for `nav_host_fragment`:

```xml
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
```

The navigation is happening using this `navigation/mobile_navigation.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/nav_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.sohamerp.marsremedies.fragment.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:name="com.sohamerp.marsremedies.fragment.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_my_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_privacy_policy"
        android:name="com.sohamerp.marsremedies.fragment.PrivacyPolicyFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_privacy_policy"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_privacy_policy" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_terms"
        android:name="com.sohamerp.marsremedies.fragment.TermsConditionFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_terms"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_terms_condition" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_contact_us"
        android:name="com.sohamerp.marsremedies.fragment.ContactUsFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_contact_us"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_terms_condition" />

</navigation>
```

### What I want to do:

Now I want to pass some values as a bundle (arguments) in Fragment when it's called.

Scenario: I have two fragments `PrivacyPolicyFragment` and `TermsConditionsFragment`, In both fragments, I am just opening links inside WebView accordingly. So When I click on the menu item of `Privacy Policy`, I will pass a link related to the same.

In this new structure `navigation/mobile_navigation.xml` opening fragments, **How can I pass arguments?**

Any help?

Comment: Use https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So I forgot to go through this link : [Define Destination Arguments](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#define_destination_arguments)

But this answer helpful to all lazy peoples like me:

Add dependency in project level **build.gradle**:

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.1.0"
```

Apply plugin in app level **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
```

#### Using XML: predefined (static) value:

In xml file of navigation **/navigation/mobile_navigation.xml** declare `argument` tag as below or you can design through [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#define_destination_arguments):

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_privacy_policy"
    android:name="com.sohamerp.marsremedies.fragment.PrivacyPolicyFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_privacy_policy"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_privacy_policy" >
    <argument
        android:name="privacyPolicyLink"
        app:argType="string"
        android:defaultValue="http://sohamerp.com/avo/avo_privacy_policy.html"/>
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_terms"
    android:name="com.sohamerp.marsremedies.fragment.PrivacyPolicyFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_terms"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_terms_condition" >
    <argument
        android:name="privacyPolicyLink"
        app:argType="string"
        android:defaultValue="http://sohamerp.com/avo/avo_privacy_policy.html"/>
</fragment>
```

Now you have to write code in your Fragment like:

```
if(getArguments() != null) {
    // The getPrivacyPolicyLink() method will be created automatically.
    String url = PrivacyPolicyFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).getPrivacyPolicyLink();
}
```

Hope it will helps you others.

Comment: Alternatively, to generate Kotlin code suitable for Kotlin-only modules add: `apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin" `

Comment: can we use bundle to pass data?

Comment: how can you pass data? like from here:`Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action);`

Comment: @sophin  From the docs: "Safe Args is strongly recommended for navigating and passing data, because it ensures type-safety.
In some cases, for example if you are not using Gradle, you can't use the Safe Args plugin. In these cases, you can use Bundles to directly pass data."

Comment: How can I pass an imageView via Safe Args from one fragment to another?

Comment: what if i'd like to pass new bundles to the current fragment from Activity?

I know we can do something like below, but is there another way to not pop back stack and re-navitate? thanks!
{
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    val id = navController.currentDestination?.id
    navController.popBackStack(id!!, true)
    navController.navigate(id, bundle)
}

Answer (score 40):

Simple and fast solution:

***pass arguments between destinations***

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("amount", amount);
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.confirmationAction, bundle);
```

**and receiving**

```
TextView tv = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAmount);
tv.setText(getArguments().getString("amount"));
```

Answer (score 15):

In this scenario, you can use

```
  private NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
  // Create the Bundle to pass, you can put String, Integer, or serializable object
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("link","http://yourlink.com/policy");
  bundle.putSerializable("USER", user); // Serializable Object
  navController.navigate(R.id.nav_terms, bundle); // called fragment with agruments
```

In case of any help you can reply on it

Comment: How to get the bundle in the R.id.nav_terms ?

Comment: in the next fragment, in onCreateView, call the  Bundle arguments = getArguments();
        if (arguments != null) { }

Comment: in Kotlin requireArguments() throws IllegalStateException if there is no Bundle, I had to use a catch block

Comment: In adition to @Vivek Handle response, inside the if clause you have to do something like arguments.get("KEY_ID").
Example:         
if (arguments != null) {
   user = (User) arguments.get("User"); }

Answer (score 11):

To pass arguments to other Fragments/Destinations, use [Safe Args](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args) which ensures type safety. Just like @bromden illustrated, Safe Args will generate a class for each fragment/destination where an `action` originates. You can then pass the arguments into the `action` that navigates to the Fragments.

In the receiving fragment, say `PrivacyFragment` if your code is in Kotlin, use by `navArgs()` property delegate to access the arguments. i.e.

```
val args: PrivacyFragmentArgs by navArgs()
```

To better understand this, visit [Pass data between destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data)

Answer (score 4):

In newer version of Android Studio 3.2+, below dependency and plug-in need to add in both build.gradle file

**Step-1**

Add **dependency** in **Project-Level** *build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5'
}
```

Apply **plugins** in **App-Level** *build.gradle*

```
plugins {
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' 
}
```

**Step-2**

1. In Navigation file, **res/navigation/nav_graph.xml**
2. Declare **argument** tag in any **fragment** or inner fragment with **action** tag
3. List item

> Sample xml code

```
 <fragment
     android:id="@+id/nav_register"
     android:name="com.pd.demo.ui.profile.RegisterFragment"
     android:label="@string/title_register"
     tools:layout="@layout/fragment_register">
     <action
         android:id="@+id/action_nav_register_to_nav_verify_otp"
         app:destination="@id/nav_verify_otp">
         <argument
             android:name="mobile"
             app:argType="string" />
         <argument
             android:name="password"
             app:argType="string" />
     </action>
 </fragment>
```

**Step-3**

Below Kotlin code, pass argument to destination fragment

```
val bundle = bundleOf("mobile" to binding.etMobileNo.text.toString().trim())
Navigation.findNavController(binding.root).navigate(R.id.action_nav_register_to_nav_verify_otp, bundle)
```

**Step-4**

Below Kotlin code, get bundle argument from source fragment

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    mobileNo = arguments!!.getString("mobile").toString()
    password = arguments!!.getString("password").toString()
}
```

This code will helps

Answer (score 2):

You could implement `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` 
And do something like this:

```
 override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
   drawer_layout.closeDrawers()

        if (item.itemId == nv_navigation_drawer_navigation_view.checkedItem?.itemId)
            return false

     Handler().postDelayed({
                when (item.itemId) {
                    R.id.nav_privacy_policy -> {
                           val action = FragmentDirections.actionFragmentToPrivacyFragment("Policy link")

                     findNavController().navigate(action)

                    }
                }
            }, DRAWER_NAVIGATION_DELAY)
  return true
    }
```

And in xml you can add argument to the recieving fragment, in this case

```
   <fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_privacy_policy"
    android:name=".fragment.PrivacyPolicyFragment"
    android:label="@string/menu_privacy_policy"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_privacy_policy">

    <argument
        android:name="policy"
        app:argType="string" />
</fragment>
```

Comment: So can you give answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59434942/android-navigation-component-not-working-with-both-navigation-and-navigation

Comment: What is `FragmentDirections` here?

Comment: FragmentDirections is class generated by SafeArgs.

Answer (score 2):

For Fragments Uri(String) example(Kotlin):

**First Fragment:**

```
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putString("uri", imageuri)
            findNavController()
            .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment, args)
```

**Second Fragment:**

```
        val uri = arguments?.getString("uri")
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "URI: $uri", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass serializable objects, enum values and arrays of primitive types.
For example:

```
enum class ObjectType : Serializable {
    FIRST, SECOND
}
```

Then, add arguments to the xml

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
        android:name="com.sohamerp.marsremedies.fragment.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_my_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" >

        <argument
            android:name="myObjectType"
            android:defaultValue="SECOND"
            app:argType="com.project.app.data.ObjectType" />
</fragment>
```

**Note, that you should specify complete path!**

Answer (score 1):

Passing data from the start destination with NavController NavGraph navigate is straightforward. I use this to display order lines associated to an order header:

```
    private void showRepositionLinesFragment(AppObjects.RepOrderHeader orderHeader) {

    int number = orderHeader.getOrderNumber();
    String orderNumber = String.format("%06d",number);
    String createDate = orderHeader.getCreateDate();
    Globals.LogTrace(this, AppAlertDialog.DialogType.Info,
        "Navigate to FragRepoLines with orderNumber: " + orderNumber,false);
    NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(FragmentRepositionHeaders.this);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(getString(R.string.arg_header_ordernumber),orderNumber);
    bundle.putString(getString(R.string.arg_repheader_createdate), createDate);
    navController.getGraph().findNode(R.id.FragRepoLines).setLabel(orderNumber + " " + createDate);
    navController.navigate(R.id.action_FragRepoHeaders_to_FragRepoLines,bundle);
}
```

Getting data from the fragment that handles the order lines turned to be more complicated. Tried for hours with NavController getArguments().
In the end this is what worked for me.

In the start fragment:

```
    NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
    // We use a String here, but any type that can be put in a Bundle is supported
    MutableLiveData<String> liveData = navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry()
        .getSavedStateHandle()
        .getLiveData(getString(R.string.arg_header_ordernumber));
    liveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(String s) {
            Globals.LogTrace(this, AppAlertDialog.DialogType.Info, "+++++++++  liveData changed -> " + s, false);
        }
    });
```

In the destination fragment:

```
    String arg = getString(R.string.arg_header_ordernumber);
    NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
    NavBackStackEntry navBackStackEntry = navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry();
    if (navBackStackEntry != null) {
        SavedStateHandle savedStateHandle = navBackStackEntry.getSavedStateHandle();
        if (savedStateHandle != null) {
            savedStateHandle.set(arg, "000000");
        } else {
            Globals.LogTrace(this, AppAlertDialog.DialogType.Info,"savedStateHandle == null",false);
        }
    } else {
        Globals.LogTrace(this, AppAlertDialog.DialogType.Info,"navBackStackEntry == null",false);
    }
```

Source: [Interact programmatically with the Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result)

I changed the navController.getPreviousBackStackEntry() for navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry()

Answer (score 0):

**Fragment 1**

```
 Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
  bundle.putInt("id",1);
  Fragment fragment=Fragment1.this; //current fragment name
  fragment.setArguments(bundle);
  NavHostFragment.findNavController(fragment)
  .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment,bundle);
  //1st arug is navigation action app:destination name defined in nav.graph
```

**Fragment 2**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = SecondFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    Bundle bundle=getArguments();
    Integer id=bundle.getInt("id");
    Toast.makeText(requireContext() , id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();});
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Kotlin** 
**Sender Fragment**

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("key", "value")
findNavController().navigate(R.id.your_action,bundle)
```

**Receiver Fragment**

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        var value= arguments?.getString("key", "")
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue but I´m still not able to pass the arguments using fragment directions. Since I need the value in several of my fragments I decided to use a companion object in my main activity. It´s probably not the best but it solves the problem:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
    companion object{
        var myGlobalVar = "Example"
    }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {....
```

Then I can access its value in all of my fragments by importing it:

```
import myAppPackage.MainActivity.Companion.myGlobalVar
```

I had to delete the argument from my navGraph but i can still access it in the background.