# Send call back to previous fragment with data using navigation graph

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, material-design, navgraph

I am using navigation graph for the first time so need help regarding the same.

In my application I have MainActivity with 5 nested graphs.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/main_navigation" app:startDestination="@+id/home_navigation"> <include app:graph="@navigation/home_navigation" /> <include app:graph="@navigation/explorer_navigation" /> <include app:graph="@navigation/favourite_navigation" /> <include app:graph="@navigation/server_navigation" /> <include app:graph="@navigation/settings_navigation" /> </navigation>`

Now, I need suggestion for below things

1.Need to implement a common error screen for multiple error types with an action button.

2.Need to provide call back from this error screen on pressing action button with some data on previous screen

3.I also want to send action from child navigation to parent navigation to navigate on other destination.

Thankyou in advance.

For 1st, Currently I have added error fragment for separately for each nested graph which added overhead to handle error page separately.

`

```
<action android:id="@+id/action_global_fragment_settings"
    app:destination="@id/fragment_settings"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_settings"
    android:name="com.xyz.android.ui.settings.SettingsBaseFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_settings">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fragment_settings_to_fragment_error"
        app:destination="@id/fragment_error" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_fragment_settings_to_settings_details_fragment"
        app:destination="@id/fragment_settings_details" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_error"
    android:name="com.xyz.android.ui.nodata.ErrorBaseFragment">
    <argument
        android:name="title"
        android:defaultValue="NO_DATA"
        app:argType="string" />
    <argument
        android:name="errorType"
        app:argType="com.xyz.android.ui.nodata.EnumErrorType"
        android:defaultValue="NO_DATA" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_settings_details"
    android:name="com.xyz.android.ui.settings.SettingsBaseFragmentDetails">
    <argument
        android:name="settingsConfig"
        app:argType="com.xyz.android.ui.settings.beans.SettingsConfigHelper$SettingsConfig" />
</fragment>
```

`

For 2nd, Still I have not found way to send call back to previous fragment with data.

For 3rd, I have used shared view model but need better approach.

Comment: you can implement a global action on Error fragment for point 1 and when on this fragment during action button you can send arguments or as you are using sharedViewModel , you can update the livedata with new values and pop the backstack to return to previous fragment. Thus your point will be covered. I couldn't understand the point 3.

Comment: @VivekGupta Thank you vivek! This is very much helpful. Though 3rd point got resolved, I had to navigate to a destination using parent controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of techniques I use to manage navigation, while keeping code fairly simple:

**ERROR SCREENS**

I find separation of error summary and detail useful. My demo app renders an [error summary fragment](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_error_summary.xml) in the containing fragment, to avoid the need for navigation just to present an error. In my demo app this renders a red link:

[image: error summary]

When the red text is clicked, an [error details fragment](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authsamples/basicmobileapp/views/errors/ErrorDetailsDialogFragment.kt) is displayed as a modal dialog, which again avoids navigation, and makes it easy to return a result to the current fragment:

[image: error details]

**NAVIGATION FROM A FRAGMENT**

A fragment can ask the navigation system to update the current location, as in [this example code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authsamples/basicmobileapp/views/companies/CompaniesFragment.kt#L116):

```kotlin
val args = Bundle()
args.putString(Constants.ARG_COMPANY_ID, viewModelItem.company.id.toString())
findNavController().navigate(R.id.transactions_fragment, args)
```

**EVENTS**

When navigation gets complex, a publish subscribe model of communication is often useful. For example, I like [this EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) project. Any view can register for events like this:

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
fun onMessageEvent(event: ReloadDataEvent) {
    this.reloadData(event.someData)
}
```

Then any other view can raise the event, when something happens that means other views should be informed, eg to reload their data. The code needed is pretty simple also.

```kotlin
EventBus.getDefault().post(ReloadDataEvent(someData))
```

**DEMO APP**

If any of this is useful you can [run my demo app](https://authguidance.com/basicandroidapp-execution/) and adapt its code to your own preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Pass data between destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/use-graph/pass-data)?

by clicking on each fragment in navigation graph window, you can define arguments of arbitrary type in right tools panel (Arguments). For more deatials see
[Android Navigation Component : Pass value (arguments) in fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59452243/6576302)

[image]: